# Getting error on input []: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

**Task:**
There is a database saved in a file named "`city_data.db`" containing a table named "cities" with columns (`"country_code", "city_name", "region", "population", "latitude", "longitude"`).

Write a *function* named "`get_us_cities`" that takes no parameters and returns a list. The returned list should contain all of the cities stored in the database that are in the United States. Each element of the returned list should be a list itself with all 6 values from the database for each city as its values. Note that the country code for the United States is "*us*".

My attempt:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("city_data.db")
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
def get_us_cities():
    get_city = c.execute("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_code='us'")
    return [x for x, in get_city]
```

I am getting error on input []: too many values to unpack (expected 1). How can I fix this?

Comment: It seem you have an unnecessary coma in your list: [x for x in get_city]

Comment: Yeah, you were right. But, is there ever a time a comma like that would ever be necessary in a list because I saw someone use that for a similar problem and the test cases still retained the right results.

Comment: You’re welcome. Not that I’m aware of, coma are used to separate elements in a list but not when unpacking another object I think.

Comment: Yes if you want to unwrap len-1 tuples, you'd use the `x,` syntax. For len-2 (ordered pairs), you'd use `x, y` etc.